# Plot 2 student T distributions with different center values

Tags: plotting, distributions

Plot 2 student T distributions with different center values µ, but same DOF.

The center values,µ has to be 45 and 48, DOF shall be 9.

Comment: And the problem is ...

Comment: Welcome! This sounds like homework - please elaborate.

Comment: To expand on Yves' comment, homework questions are allowed here, but we would like to see where exactly you are having trouble with the problem.

Comment: I was going to make an illustration, but somehow i messed it up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find the list of supported distributions using:  `?? *Distribution`.  Then click on the StudentTDistribution to get the support page, where you'll read: `StudentTDistribution[μ,σ,ν] represents a Student t distribution with location parameter μ, scale parameter σ, and ν degrees of freedom`.  As such, it is a simple matter to then simply plot the distributions this way:

```
Plot[
    {
       PDF[StudentTDistribution[45, 1, 9], x], 
       PDF[StudentTDistribution[48, 1, 9], x]
    }, 
    {x, -5, 5}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Incidentally, in case you don't know, you can understand the Student t distribution as follows.  Suppose you have a normal (Gaussian) distribution with unknown mean mu and standard deviation sigma and you want to estimate its mean by selecting (sampling) a fixed number of points, nu, from that Gaussian and computing their average.  (Generally, nu is fairly small number.)  Suppose nu = 6.  You sample 6 points from the Gaussian and compute their average.  It will likely be close the the Gaussian's mean, but not exactly---sometimes that value will be a bit higher than mu, sometimes a bit less.  Now choose another set of 6 points from the Gaussian and compute their mean.  If you repeat such sampling many times and record the means, you'll get a distribution of those computed means, of course centered on the mean of the Gaussian.  This is the Student t distribution.  Clearly, because of the symmetry of a Gaussian itself with respect to its mean mu (the shape above mu is the same as the shape below mu, but reversed), the student t distribution is also symmetric with respect to mu.  However, because by simple combinatorics, it is unlikely all your six points will be above mu or all below mu, and thus it will be rare to get computed means that deviate greatly from mu (as compared to the Gaussian itself)  As a result, the student t distribution will be narrower and more peaked at mu than is the Gaussian.

Now, if instead of choosing 6 points you choose nu = 50 points, then it becomes even less likely that the distribution of computed means will deviate from mu by much:  Thus the student t distribution gets narrower as the number of points (degrees of freedom) gets larger.  You can try plotting such distributions with different values of nu to gain intuition about this important distribution.

Comment: By solving an easy homework question right away instead of giving food for thought you're hardly helping anyone.

Comment: Edited to remove my own downvote. But please don't feed lazy leeches here